# Why is it Wrong to use what in place of which (Context of American English) | Specific to GMAT

Tags: word-usage, which-what, what-that

(B) According to some analysts, the gains in the stock market reflect growing confidence in the economy to avoid the recession, what many feared earlier in the year, rather to come

This is an excerpt from GMAT Question.

some instructor has given this response -
* it appears that this choice is trying to substitute "what" for "which". that is not acceptable.

Can some one explain in detail why the usage of what is wrong here?

The whole complete sentence -

According to some analysts, the gains in the stock market reflect growing confidence **that the economy will avoid the recession that many had feared earlier in the year and instead come** in for a “soft landing,” followed by a gradual increase in business activity.

(A) that the economy will avoid the recession that many had feared earlier in the year and instead come

(B) in the economy to avoid the recession, what many feared earlier in the year, rather to come

(C) in the economy’s ability to avoid the recession, something earlier in the year many had feared, and instead to come

(D) in the economy to avoid the recession many were fearing earlier in the year, and rather to come

(E) that the economy will avoid the recession that was feared earlier this year by many, with it instead coming

Which one is correct. It is GMAT question.

Comment: This is not duplicate, but a very specific post.

Comment: Please read about what constitutes a 'duplicate' on Meta. And read Araucaria's answer.

Comment: You haven't given us the whole sentence. If you had given us the whole sentence (which I found on the internet)  we could have told you that the instructor doesn't know what he's talking about. There is nothing wrong with the *what* ... rather it's the *rather to come* that is wrong.

Comment: Added the whole sentence. Actually the instructor is Ron Purewal, content creator of Manhattan GMAT. GMAC has some subsets of english usage.

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually asking here. What are (A) to (E) in relation to the bolded bit?

Comment: Ok let me re post it. I have reposted A, B, C , D and E only one option is correct among 5 options available

Comment: It doesn't matter who the instructor is. He's wrong. *"growing confidence that the economy will avoid the recession, rather to come in for a soft landing"* has two verbs in non-parallel tenses connected by *rather*, which is not a conjunction. And I see nothing wrong with the appositive clause *"what many feared earlier in the year."*

Comment: Actually, it's a reasonable mistake on the instructor's part. Most of the time you can't substitute *what* for *which*. It's just that in this case the structure of the sentence is set up so you can, and I assume he gave his answer without thinking it over carefully enough.

Comment: what is not a Noun how can it open an appositive clause?

Comment: If it's not an appositive clause, (B) is ungrammatical because *what* can't have an antecedent. (See the duplicate question.) So you've answered your own question.